# Im tying to register a service in eureka and im getting the following error

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

After setting up my eureka server. I went to the service that i want to register and in the main class i added this annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient. After that i went to application.properties and add this configuration<eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka and after that i added this to the pom spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client . And after starting the application im getting this exception and i think i did everything right.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClientsProperties]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh dependencies. If you just add dependency to pom file it wouldn't be installed automatically.
I'm not using maven, but I think the following should work for you. Just run these commands within command line in root directory of project.

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Comment: That didnt do the trick but thank you

Comment: Could you provide your pom file?